# A design of modules and interface

Tags: ocaml

I would like to define an interface `PROPERTY`, and at least 2 modules `Type` and `Formula` matching it:

```
module type PROPERTY =
sig
  type t
  val top : t
  val bot : t
  val to_string: t -> string
  val union: t -> t -> t
  val intersection: t -> t -> t
end

module Type = (struct
  type t =
   | Tbot
   | Tint
   | Tbool
   | Ttop
  ...      
end: PROPERTY)

module Formula = (struct
  type t =
   | Fbot
   | Ftop
   | Fplus of int * Type.t
   ...
  let union = 
   ... Type.union ...
  ...      
end: PROPERTY)
```

There are two requirements:

1) I would like the constructors of `Type` can be called outside (all the programs if necessary)

2) A part of some values of `Formula` contain values of `Types`, for instance `Fplus (5, Type.Tint)` is of type `Formula`; also some functions of `Formula` would need to call some functions of `Type`, for example, `Formula.union` needs to call `Type.union`

Could anyone tell me how to amend the declaration above to fullfil my requirements? Extra modules can be added if necessary...

Comment: Drive-by comment (orthogonal to gasche's reply): you can write declarations with a signature ascription conveniently as `module X : SIG = ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't apply the `: PROPERTY` sealing casts to the module declaration. This hides the extra information from the returned module. You should rather use:

```
 module Type = struct .. end
 module Formula = struct .. end
```

If you still want to check that `Type` and `Formula` do satisfy the `PROPERTY` interface, you can do that separately:

```
 let () =
   ignore (module Type : PROPERTY);
   ignore (module Formula : PROPERTY);
   ()
```

Comment: The purpose of applying the `: PROPERTY` is that later I am going to make a functor with `PROPRETY` as arguments: `module ZFUN = functor (Prop : PROPERTY) -> struct ... end`

Comment: You don't need to force the abstract interface at the place of declaration of `Type` and `Formula`. An interface satisfaction check will happen when you apply the `ZFUN` functor.